# How to alias a table while updating the same table from itself?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

How do you alias a table while updating the same table from itself?

My Query:

```
update accounts set adusername = x.adusername 
from Accounts x
where x.AccountName = accounts.rev and x.ok>10 and accounts.ok in (0,1,2,3) 
and x.ADUserName is not null and accounts.ADUserName is null
```

Errors

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "accounts.rev" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "accounts.ok" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "accounts.ok" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "accounts.ok" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "accounts.ok" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "accounts.ADUserName" could not be bound.
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: @Ullas that is the actual query i am working with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.adusername = x.adusername 
FROM Accounts x
INNER JOIN Accounts a ON x.AccountName = a.rev
WHERE x.ok>10
    AND a.ok in (0,1,2,3) 
    AND x.ADUserName is not null
    AND a.ADUserName is null
```

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible with sub queries or joins:

```
UPDATE accounts SET adusername = 'ABC'
FROM Accounts AS x
WHERE x.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Accounts WHERE Accounts.Username = 'XYZ') AND x.OK in (0,1,2,3)
```

or

```
UPDATE accounts SET adusername = x.adusername 
FROM Accounts
  JOIN Accounts AS x ON Accounts.ID = x.ID
WHERE x.Username = 'XYZ' AND Accounts.OK in (0,1,2,3)
```

should do the job.